# How do I resolve an issue with an "invalid Python SDK" after cloning a GitHub repository?

Tags: python, git, github, pycharm, sdk

My research collaborator and I are trying to share python scripts so that we can both make changes and work on the project (using PyCharm) at the same time.

One of us created a repository on GitHub, named cep-occ-spec, uploaded the scripts and virtual environment, and is now able to use the PyCharm-GitHub integration to commit/push changes (and view these on GitHub as they happen).

I have invited my colleague to the GitHub repository as a collaborator, and I instructed them on cloning the repository using the PyCharm interface on their system. This seems to have worked - we have verified that the repository contents (scripts and venv) have been saved into the selected local directory. However, when we try to set the Python interpreter to this same local directory (cep-occ-spec > venv > Scripts > python.exe), as I have successfully done, my collaborator gets the following error message:

> Invalid Python SDK
>
> Cannot set up a python SDK at Python 3.10 (cep-occ-spec) (C:\Users\Ola\Documents\GitHub\cep-occ-spec\venv\Scripts\python.exe). The SDK seems invalid.

We initially thought it may have something to do with the underlying Python software that we each have, but we have un-installed and make sure we both have the same version (3.10.5). We are now at a bit of a loss... Does anyone kindly have any ideas about why this may be happening?

Comment: can you post the exact output of `python --version` ?

Comment: Hi @OrenIshShalom. The Python interpreter for my collaborator is (Python 3.10 (cep-occ-spec)), which is identical to mine. But in their case they get a message at the bottom saying "Python Packaging Tools not found. Install packaging tools". It is when they click on that that the error message pops up. Additionally, on the Project side bar, their venv folder (and contents) are in orange. Not sure if this helps...?

Comment: no :) it doesn't help :) can you run `python --version` from PowerShell ? or cmd ?

Comment: Hi @OrenIshShalom. This is what we both get: Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Do you use .gitignore file? Maybe you ignore some files, so on your PC all files are present, but they are not pushed to remote. So when your colleague clones repo, he does not have all the files. But overall, storing `exe` file in git is not a good idea, at all... Git is not for this.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this just in case someone else comes here from the same search that I did.

I cloned a repo and then had the same error. The end result was that the project was trying to use the wrong interpreter. Going into *Settings > Project: ProjectName > Python Interpreter*, then opening the dropdown list for Python Interpreter (Not the 'Add Interpreter' button), there were two interpreters listed.. one for the whole PC - "*Python 3.11*", and one for the project - "*Python 3.11 (ProjectName)*". Choosing the second of those fixed it for me.

Hope this helps someone else.